# AWS Cloud watch log is broken

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a nestJS application running on ECS (AWS), my cloud watch log is broken, each json line is a log line.

Image below:

[image]

Anybody suggest an idea

Comment: What do you mean by "is broken"? Are you wanting all those lines as a single log entry? How is your application sending that data to the log?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the full json as text. (You can still redact sensitive fields)

Comment: I bilieve use this plugin solver my problem: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/set-up-a-logger-for-your-node-app-with-winston-and-cloudwatch-in-5-minutes-dec0c6c0d5b8